# Setting the types (dtypes) of a multiindex DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Say I got this multiindex `DataFrame`:

```
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame(index=range(3), columns=pandas.MultiIndex.from_product(
        (('A', 'B'), ('C', 'D'), ('E', 'F'))))
>>> df
     A                   B                                                                             
     C         D         C         D                                                                   
     E    F    E    F    E    F    E    F                                                              
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN                                                              
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN                                                              
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
>>> df.dtypes                                                                                          
A  C  E    object                                                                                      
      F    object                                                                                      
   D  E    object                                                                                      
      F    object                                                                                      
B  C  E    object                                                                                      
      F    object                                                                                      
   D  E    object                                                                                      
      F    object
```

How would I set the type of all columns `E` to `float64` and all columns `F` to `int64`? I.e., so that `df.dtypes` returns the following:

```
A  C  E    float64                                                                                      
      F    int64                                                                                      
   D  E    float64                                                                                      
      F    int64                                                                                      
B  C  E    float64                                                                                      
      F    int64                                                                                      
   D  E    float64                                                                                      
      F    int64
```

I know about `DataFrame.astype` and it works fine for singly indexed `DataFrame`'s but how would I use it with multiindexing? In the real code the number of columns are a lot higher: still three levels, but columns reaching couple of millions.

I've been searching the web and the documentation though I can't find the answer. It feels like I've misunderstood something about the `DataFrame` concept and that I'm wrong in wanting what I want.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integer columns of NaNs aren't supported on older versions, but starting from v0.24, you can use the nullable dtype. Select column slices using `pd.IndexSlice`, then set the type like this:

```
pd.__version__
# '0.24.2'

for cval, dtype in [('E', 'float64'), ('F', 'Int64')]:
    df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, :,cval]] = (
        df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, :,cval]].astype(dtype))
```

```
df.dtypes
A  C  E    float64
      F      Int64
   D  E    float64
      F      Int64
B  C  E    float64
      F      Int64
   D  E    float64
      F      Int64
dtype: object
```

Note that the `I` in `Int64` is capitalized to represent a [Nullable Integer Type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html#nullable-integer-data-type).

Comment: Thank you. Of course, you don't know the particulars of my "case" or what I want to achieve, but would you say that wanting types set up like this make sense in the world of `pandas`? It seems so logical to me that I would have expected the types of each column to easily be set through the constructor, but no. Which makes me think I'm being "unidiomatic".

Comment: @ryhp usually dataframes are initialised with data, and pandas will infer the dtype of columns from there. So, this is not a common requirement, which is why it looks as clunky as it does.